# Multiple Autocomplete Textview

Tags: android, autocomplete

On this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) on the android devs about AutoCompleteTextView.
Would I need to create multiple instances of xml layout textview if I have multiple AutoCompleteTextView or would using one would be sufficient and place each on an ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one list_item XML file. You can re-use that layout for each of your AutoCompleteTextView instances/views. I believe you can even re-use the adapter if the list of auto-complete words are the same.

Comment: Thank you I just needed to confirm it.